# ionic: http post request works in browser but not in mobile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, http-post

I am calling a simple authentication API in my application using `$http.post`.

```
 this.login = function(scope, credentials) {
     var url = REST_API.DOMAIN + REST_API.LOGIN;
     $http.post(url, $.param(credentials)/* convert from json to query string */, {
         headers: {
             'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
         }
     })
     .success (function(response){
         $log.info(response);
     })
     .error(function(data, status, header, config){
          $log.error(data);
     });
}
```

My code works seamlessly when I test it in browser using the following command:

> ionic serve

But when I launch it in my phone:

> ionic run -lc android

The error callback function is called immediately with response data being null:

[image]

This piece of code used to work but at some point in time it's stopped working. The only thing I remember doing that could have affected this behavior is installing newer version of android:

> cordova platform remove android
>   cordova platform add android@5.1.1

Another point that I've noticed: I am sending the http request to a web service on localhost. But if I host the webservice code on a remote server the http request will work successfully on my phone.

Comment: Did you check it threw any cors error?

Comment: @RameshRajendran Yes it aint the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you upload your code to your phone ,the localhost becomes your phone, not your computer. So there is no server on your phone that listens, so it gives an error. To fix this, when trying on your phone change localhost to the IP of your computer , which you can learn by typing `ipconfig` in Windows and `ifconfig` in Linux. Write the number starts with `192.168....` or `10....` instead of `localhost`. That way it will also work on your computer. It is also the same reason why it works when you send it to a remote server.

Comment: Thank you it was fixed :) I don't know why I think `localhost` used to work before...

Comment: How to change localhost to IP address in ionic?help!

Comment: @jose just change the string in your connection url with the ip

Comment: @atayenel i changed its working fine browser but not in mobile device